# Multiple Select - Chosen jQuery

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, jquery-chosen

I am using the Harvest Chosen jQuery plugin successfully to create a drop down single selection list with a submit button on a Wordpress site. This is connected up to display all terms from a given taxonomy, and allows a user to choose a term and then press a submit button to load the corresponding page relating to the selected term.

I am now trying to get the plugin to work with multiple selections of terms from the taxonomy. I have the selection working and on the front-end a user can select multiple terms, but I cannot figure out how to submit the multiple selections.

I know my code is missing something, but I can't figure out what needs modifying to allow multiple terms to be selected.

This is what I have so far:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<div>
<?php
function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
    $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
    $output ="<select name='topics' class='chosen' style='width:500px' multiple='true'>";
    foreach($myterms as $term){
        $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
        $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $term_name = $term->name;
        $link = $term_slug;
        $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";

}
    $output .="</select>";
return $output;
}

$taxonomies = array('topics');
$args = array();
echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);

?>
<div><input type="submit" value="Filter" /></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Ordinarily, for multiple selections, the URL structure would look like the following for an 'AND' query:

```
domain.com/?topics=topic1+topic2+topic3
```

OR the following for an 'OR' query:

```
domain.com/?topics=topic1,topic2,topic3
```

Getting either of these options would work for now (I eventually intend to add an option for AND/OR searches)

Any help or pointers in the right direction to get this working would be great.

Comment: If you're using PHP, it might be expecting a query string such as `?topics[]=topic1&topics[]=topic2&topics[]=topic3&mode=AND`. Let me know if this is OK.

Comment: Hi Salman. If I select just a single value from the multiple select drop down, then the submit works just fine and the first '?' is appended to the url. The problem comes with multiple selections where the submit simply chooses the last value selected, and loads that page...

Comment: If I select a single value from the multiple dropdown the submit works fine and the first '?' is added to the url. The problem comes with multiple selections where the submit chooses the last value selected, and loads that page...If I edit $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>"; to say $output .="<option value='".letter."".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>"; this will then create urls like: domain.com/?topics=letterTOPIC1&topics=letterTOPIC2 which I was hoping I could alter using str_replace but & , + / etc are urlencoded and I can't find a way to str_replace them.

Comment: I highly recommend using Select2 over Chosen. Chosen never really got finished. It was a great start... Select2 is much more complete, less bugs, gets developed, and supports modern concepts like Responsive Design. And it works basically the same, so the conversion is pretty easy. http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form, you could build the URL with JavaScript and change the page with something like:

```
$('form').submit( function() {
    var selectArray = $('select').val();
    var newURL = "http://domain.com/?topics=";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectArray.length; i++) {
        if ( 1 != 0 ) {
            newURL += "+";
        }
        newURL += selectArray[i];
    }
    window.location = newURL;
});
```

Breakdown: `$('form').submit( function() { [...] });` gets fired when a form is submitted. You would want to qualify this with a class `$('form.yourClass')` or ID `$('form#yourID')`  unique to your form.

`$('select').val()` will return an array of the selected values for a selet element. It should be qualified in the same way as the form with a class `$('select.yourClass')` or an ID `$('select#yourID')`. The JavaScript goes through the array and appends each value to the root URL of `http://domain.com/?topics=` with a `+` in between each value. Once it is done, the user is redirected to the new URL.

Comment: Hi Matthew - could you expand a little on how I would implement this? My Javascript skills are pretty slim i'm afraid...

Comment: That is jQuery. '$('form').submit( function() { } )' will get fired when any form on the page is submitted. You can qualify it with an ID like `$('form#myFormID')` or a class like `$('form.myFormClass')`. $('select').val() will return the value of a select element. You can qualify it the same way to get the correct one. I'll add more details to my example.