# populate chosen multiple get plugin with ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, get, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I am having trouble with populating chosen plugin multiple get with data from an ajax call. I tired following the below posts,

[Jquery Chosen plugin - dynamically populate list by Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044330/jquery-chosen-plugin-dynamically-populate-list-by-ajax)

[Multiple Select - Chosen jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305836/multiple-select-chosen-jquery)

[Jquery chosen ajax call populate multiselelect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615044/jquery-chosen-ajax-call-populate-multiselelect-not-working)

But did not help. The data just doesn't get filled :( my ajax request is as follows,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
 function doGetTag() {
        alert('here');     

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php/rest/resource/qtag',
            //data: data,               
            success: function(data) {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
                var tags = "";
                var curVal = document.getElementById('tags').innerHTML;

                for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
                    var tagObj = jsonObj[i];
                    //document.write("<option>" + tagObj.tagName + "</option>");
                    var tagHtml = "<option>" + tagObj.tagName + "</option></br>";
                    tags = tags + tagHtml ;
                }

                tagTotal = curVal + tags;
                document.getElementById('tags').innerHTML = tagTotal;            
                alert( document.getElementById('tags').innerHTML);
            },
            type: "get"     
        });
 }   
 </script>
```

which returns a json string. the data gets properly displayed over here if I alert it out on a message box. But the issue is how to populate the multiple get plugin? following is my html,

```
 <select data-placeholder="Tag your question here" style="width:350px;height:50px;" multiple class="chosen-select" id="tags">
      <option value="" ></option>

 </select>
```

I am very new to this plugin and would very much appreciate your help :)

**FYI**

I did it using direct php as follows,

```
 <select data-placeholder="Tag your question here" style="width:350px;height:50px;" multiple class="chosen-select" id="tags">
      <option value="" ></option>

               <?php
                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tags");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo"<option>".$row['tagName']."</option>";
                        echo"</br>";
                    }
                ?>
   </select>
```

and it properly displays the data, but the project requirement states it is a **MUST to use AJAX** request to populate data. Thank you very much :) your expert advice is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all check your **url:** 'index.php/rest/resource/qtag',

This may work :

```
success: function(data) {

   $("#tags").html(data).trigger('liszt:updated');

}
```

where data = (echo from sourse)

> <option value=0> </option>
>   <option value=1> Option 1 </option>
>   <option value=2> Option 2  </option>